# Unable to get String.split() to work as expected on android

Tags: java, android, string, split

I want to split an email string in java (android) but it not work correctly.

```
Input: "ihnel48@gmail.com"
String[] pattens = email.split("@.");
Expected: "ihnel48", "gmail", "com"
Output: "ihnel48" "mail.com"
```

Comment: Of course it works.  You are just not using it correctly.

Comment: The problem has nothing with android.

Comment: Ok, I see. It's better when using Regular Expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because [`String.split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) matches based on a [regular expression](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), `@.` means it looks for *two* characters in a row (not *either* character once).  And, `.` in regular expressions is a special character meaning "anything":

```
@. = "@ and then any character"
```

In your case this matches "@g" and **not** the dot.

Instead, you want:

```
String[] pattens = email.split("[@.]");
```

The square brackets, `[]`, create a character class, which represents all the valid characters a single position can match. So, you need to match "`@`" or "`.`".  The character `.` does not need to be escaped inside a character class.

Comment: Nice!! You really cured my 20min headache! Thanks dude

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the period ( `.` ). Otherwise it is a wildcard and will match any single character. The way to escape it is with a backslash. In literal strings in Java, the backslash is also the escape character, so you have to use TWO backslashes. Furthermore, you need some kind of "or" operator, to tell it to split when it hits a `.` OR an `@`. There are two ways to do that.

Here's one:

```
String[] pattens = email.split("@|\\.");
```

Here's another:

```
String[] pattens = email.split("[@\\.]");
```

Answer (score 1):

the `.` matches the `g`, i.e. the `g` is also removed

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it worked perfectly.  You gave it a regular expression that said to look for the character "@" followed by any character (which is what "." means in a regular expression).  That's what it found and split on.

I'm no regex wonk, but I ***think*** that maybe "@|\." would do what you apparently intended.

Comment: So how would you look for a period in a regular expression?

Comment: You need to use a backslash to escape the . like `\.`. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String[] pattens = email.split("@");
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to split on @ or . I believe.

The correct regex for that is: `"@|\."`

Edit: put parenthesis instead of quotes originally

Answer (score 0):

Fun solution:

```
     //Replace all "." to "@", and split
     String split(String input){
        String[] patterns = input.replaceAll("\\.", "@").split("@");
        return Arrays.toString(patterns);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(CurrentString, "@");
 String first = tokens.nextToken();
 String second = tokens.nextToken();
```